# Powershell append to SQL returned Query

Tags: sql, powershell

I have the following table:

```
ID|Name |FruitOrder                           
1 |Sarah|Apple, Banana, Orange, Peach, Mangoes
2 |John |Apple, Banana                        
3 |Mary |Peach, Mangoes                       
4 |Mark |Mangoes
```

I want to take the returned sql table dataset, and append a new column called "note" to the dataset, filling each row with the string "Query1" (for simplicity) :

```
ID|Name |FruitOrder                            | Note                           
1 |Sarah|Apple, Banana, Orange, Peach, Mangoes | Query1
2 |John |Apple, Banana                         | Query1                        
3 |Mary |Peach, Mangoes                        | Query1                      
4 |Mark |Mangoes                               | Query1
```

Powershell Code, please see foreach for suggestion.

```
#powershell code
$SQLDataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.fill($SQLDataset) | out-null


foreach ($object in SQLDataset.tables){
# suggestion for logic/code please
}
```

Comment: Do you want to append the dataset in the table or a custom PS object will do?

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh -  I prefer a table. Will need to export to a CSV at the end. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newvalue = $SQLDataset |select -expand tables | select ID,Name,FruitOrder,query
```

this will add the "query" to the array, so you can then set it in your app.

You could then do a:

```
$newvalue = $newvalue | %{$_.query = "select * from table";$_}
```

and have your query on each line.

(and yes, I am sure there are easier or even better ways).